# HTC Android Crash Report Fragment OnCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In the following crash report I am seeing something weird. This happened on an HTC One running 4.3, I do not have access to these phones to debug, but it looks like it is creating my SettingFragment (extends PreferenceFragment) during my PenelopeMainActivity (extends Activity) during super.onCreate() line 236.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree/com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.PenelopeMainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1129)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2354)
at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:994)
at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:261)
at android.preference.PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:272)
at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:285)
at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.settings.SettingsFragment.onCreate(SettingsFragment.java:62)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1775)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:863)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1101)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:1989)
at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:929)
at com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.PenelopeMainActivity.onCreate(PenelopeMainActivity.java:236)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
... 11 more
```

Now SettingsFragment uses an XmlId that is set after super.OnCreate() is called. Infact there shouldn't be an instance of SettingsFragment when OnCreate() is called. Am I missing something? Could this be something to do with onStop() and onStart() vs onCreate() when the process is killed?

But it should recreate from the beginning onCreate(), not try and build the settings menu even if the settings menu was open? right?

Here is the onCreate method and xmlId set method
com.harmonicprocesses.penelopefree.settings.SettingsFragment.onCreate()

```
public SettingsFragment setXmlId(int xmlId){
    mXmlId = xmlId;
    return this;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mAct = getActivity();
    mRes = mAct.getResources();
    mFrag = getFragmentManager();
    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(mXmlId); // <<<-------------------*** LINE 62 ***
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
}
```

This is where I create the instance of SettingsFragment:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.options_menu_special_efects) {
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, SpecialEffects.class);
        mSettingsFragment = new SettingsFragment().setXmlId(R.xml.special_effects);
        mSettingsFragment.setContext(mContext)
                .setPurchaseManager(purchaseManager)
                .setAudioProcessor(mAudioProcessor)
                .setPcam(mPcamera);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSettingsFragment)
            .commit();
        mFragmentViewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mSystemUiHider.hide();
        mSystemUiHider.disable();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are somewhere puting as as a resource parameter value 0. This might seem obvious but if you dont see how it happens by looking into your code, then you should try reproduce it on emulator. If it would have anything to do with wrong lifecycle management, you would probably already reproduce it during development.

Comment: That is correct. Added some more code to show how the XmlId (which is resource parameter value 0) is set. Could this be when the orientation changes when the setting menu is open? let me test that.

Comment: Are you passing all your arguments in Bundle to your fragment - using setArguments() fragment method ?

Comment: No I didn't use a bundle. I probably should. I will update it to use Bundle args, hopefully that will remedy the error. Couldn't hurt anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, `mXmlId` is 0 based off `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0`. From looking at your `onCreate` it is no surprise. You're *relying* on `mXmlId` being set when `onCreate` is called. If your fragment is destroyed by say a screen rotation change, you will get onDestroy > onCreate called on your fragment with any saved values in the `Bundle`. You aren't using a bundle so you aren't repopulating that field.

For the record, the 'correct' way of doing this is to use `setArguments(Bundle)` to pass constructor args to a `Fragment`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html for info on the `newInstance` pattern for creating fragments.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem rotating or anything, but I will accept this as the probably cause. Hopefully this fixes it.